# KAA 8 Event Handler for Authentication

Tags: authentication, events, status, checkin, kaa

we have an issue which seems to be related with our endpoint status.bin reporting to the KAA server.  Currently, when listening to the KAA bus, we can see that there are many devices "checking in" to the server, but not able to send notifications from our custom portal.  When we remove the kaa_status.bin file, and restart our C++ Client, the issue resolves.  What I would like to know is if there is a State or Status file on the Server side that is generated with such events.  Our devices seem to be connected, however, wont communicate unless we have the status.bin file regenerated which would mean, we restart the kaa client application.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be related to initialization of the Kaa Client which breaks upon the first start and some configuration, etc data is persited locally.

Please provide the fragment of code you use for initialization of the Kaa Client and send notifications with it?

Also, please provide log output of the application (we recommend you to pass -DKAA_MAX_LOG_LEVEL=6 to CMake during build of the client for highest verbosity level).

In case you are interested in handling status of the connection to Kaa Bootstrap/Operations services, take a look at the KaaClientStateListener::onConnectionEstablished() method, which is invocated upon successful connection.

**Note**: that this method is available in C++ SDK starting from Kaa 0.10.0 release.